# Spring Boot Spring Batch deploy to Openshift

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-cloud-dataflow

I have a spring batch process that is scheduled through Cron (@Scheduled) and need to be deployed to OpenShift. When I am trying to deploy to Openshift , the middleware team has shared the logs.

Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.task.batch.listener.BatchEventAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.task.batch.listener.BatchEventAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d1732e68] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)

I have the environment specific details in the folder structure application-properties/dev/application.yml respectively.

Does Spring cloud require Spring Cloud Data Flow(SCDF) or can be a normal batch processing. They are using Spring config server and

searchPaths: 'application-properties/{​​​​​​​​profile}​​​​​​​​'
to get the credentials dynamically. Any inputs will be greatly appreciated. Not sure what is missing that is causing the error.

Comment: That is just an informational message, ignore it.

Comment: <dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
 </dependency>. and the https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/reference/html/#_client_side_usage. helped in solving the connection issues

Comment: @M.Deinum Thank you.